# Not cringe. Not used in SQL

Tags: riddle

I save lives,

I ruin lives.

If you push me, or otherwise, you'd better make sure I'm free.

Else, your strength will matter to no degree.

Even when I'm tiny.

Hint

> It is a real life object. It has no direct connection to computers.

Comment: Please edit your question to contain information as to where this riddle is sourced.

Comment: Where it's sourced? I just thought of it. The `SQL` part is a bit `knowledge`y, but it's only a minor, optional hint. I actually wouldn't have put it there were it not for the 12 character minimum title.

Comment: Nice, I was focusing on that. Ima rest and listen to THROUGH THE FIRE AND THE FLAMES to figger this out.

Comment: Is "If you push me, or otherwise, you make sure I'm free" supposed to be so grammatically broken? It would help to know what the *then* in the *if-then* is supposed to be.

Comment: @Feryll Maybe I have used too much slang and it became unclear. Changed "you make sure" to "you'd better make sure"

Comment: Is the thing used in NoSQL?

Comment: this SQL thing doomed the poor question. I'm adding a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you a

> Syringe

I save lives, I ruin lives.

> A syringe can be used both to administer life-giving medicines and deadly illegal drugs.

If you push me, or otherwise, you'd better make sure I'm free.

> If you put a syringe in your arm, you should make sure you got one from a doctor or free syringe exchange. Otherwise, you might infect yourself with something deadly

Else, your strength will matter to no degree.

> If you get HIV or another disease from a dirty syringe, you will die no matter how strong you are...

Even when I'm tiny.

> ..or how small the needle was.

Title

> Syringe sounds a little like cringe. And TTT has already solved the SQL clue.

Comment: Correct. Funnily enough, points 3 and 4 and off....the explanation is simpler, more physics stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You are:

> Drugs

I save lives,

> Medicinal drugs can save lives.

I ruin lives.

> Certain drugs can ruin lives.

If you push me, or otherwise, you'd better make sure I'm free.

> Still a little wonky here. "Pushing drugs" means "selling drugs", and any successful drug dealer knows you can't just give away your product away for free (at least not perpetually), so it seems the opposite would be true. But if you're "pushing people to take legal drugs", for example vaccines, then you better make sure they're free or else you won't be able to achieve high vaccination rates (if that's the goal), and you'll also alienate those that can't afford the drugs.

Else, your strength will matter to no degree.

> If you're addicted to drugs, physical strength doesn't really matter (though mental strength does!)

Even when I'm tiny.

> If you're addicted to drugs, and on a sober path, even a tiny amount of the drug can set you back.

Title: Not cringe.

> It's not cringe to take drugs (legal, or otherwise), or even to be an addict, or a former addict.

Title: Not used in SQL.

> Obviously we must avoid SQL injection!

Comment: Easily the best answer so far, I think

Comment: Not the answer, HOWEVER! You are VERY close, since rot13(Lbh qrpbqrq gur FDY uvag, vg vf vaqrrq gurer gb cebivqr gur jbeq "vawrpgvba"). So now thing of a slightly less general thingy in the family of things in your answer and you got it.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thx. I see someone else got the answer before I had time to edit mine, so I'm happy to take the assist. I'll leave this answer alone for historical reference.

Answer (score 2):

Is the answer maybe

> Memory

I save lives, I ruin lives

> Remembering something can save lives, like breathing. Yet memory can also ruin the lives of programmers, or even to people close to some affected by memory-debilitating diseases

If you push me, you make sure I'm free

> "Pushing" your memory would mean trying very hard to remember something, and  that's hard to do with some other things in mind

Else, your strength will matter to no degree

> No use in torturing yourself, even physically

Even when I'm tiny.

> Even with a tiny memory, strength is of no use, some things are just left forgotten

Title

> Memory is not cringe, and is not used in SQL

Comment: That's amazing. And it fits, too.

Comment: I wanted this to be the answer for a while, but I don't get the reference to cringe, can you explain that, and isn't sql sever famous for rot13(pbafhzvat znffvir nzbhagf bs ENZ, cyhf gur fdy vgfrys yvirf va naq hfrf zrzbel)?

Comment: The title is a wild guess, I don't think it's really the answer, but it fit the rest *fairly* nicely

Comment: Not the intended answer. Added a hint, seeing as so many answers did fit.

Answer (score 0):

Largely guided by the title are you

> A codebase ("based" = "not cringe" in modern youth parlance as I understand, likewise SQL is a language for databases not codebases)

I save lives,

> Not sure here, but some critical software is used by emergency services for example, or gaming software comes with multiple lives and options to save.

I ruin lives.

> Many coders would agree with this description.

If you push me, or otherwise, you make sure I'm free.

Else, your strength will matter to no degree.

Even when I'm tiny.

> If pushing a software update to a codebase managed by git for example, it is necessary to check that the current version is not being used by someone else. This applies even to minor changes.

Comment: Good try...but not really. The answer is something much more familiar to an everyday person.